# How to get the classes matching for a string in sparql?

Tags: javascript, sparql, semantic-web, ontology, dbpedia

given a user input (eg. "dog") I need to find all (or at least some) matching classes given the dbpedia ontology. I am newbie in semantics and every example I found is about concrete values from triplets. I mean, I found queries for retrieving things like:
Allie age 15
Phillipe age 21

But what I really need is retrieving possible classes given a string. for example if I search for "article", I need a query retrieving things like " ecommerce product, magazine article, constitution article, paper", etc...

What should I read to find examples like this? what libraries do you recommend for consuming this from javascript? no matter if there is a need of privileged code like greasemonkey or a browser extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help on any Javascript libraries but a SPARQL query to extract classes based on some given text could look like this -

```
select distinct ?concept ?label where {
   ?concept a <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class> .
   ?concept rdfs:label ?label .
   FILTER(regex(?label, "Dog", "i")) .
   FILTER(langMatches(lang(?label),"EN")) .
} LIMIT 100
```

This query will extract any classes with the exact name Dog. This query will need to adapted for more advanced searches but should give you a starting point.

Note: I've purposefully added `FILTER(langMatches(lang(?label),"EN")) .` to search only english labels.

Comment: **regex** is inappropriate and inefficient here.  There's a [**contains**](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-contains) function that checks string containment.